# OAjax: how to handle server offline and cache not available scanerio?

Tags: oajax.js

I am using [oajax.js](https://github.com/chasgharali/oajax.js). Is there a way to handle the case where server is offline and data is also not available in cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in given case oajax.js response with it own define error json object in which status is 404 so you can handle this in following way:

```
$oajax({url: "http://localhost/phonegap/getData.php" ,  success: function(result){
                    if(result.error){
                      //data is not found in cashe
                    }
             },
         error : function(err){
            console.log(err);
         }
    });
```